# How to extract only certain fields from CSVTOJSON in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, csvtojson

I have managed to convert CSV data to JSON using the csvtojson npm package and successfully display it in the console.

```
csvtojson()
      .fromFile(csvFilePath)
      .then(jsonObj => {
        console.log(jsonObj);
      })


[
  {
    id: '1',
    title: 'Fjallraven - Foldsack No. 1 Backpack, Fits 15 Laptops',
    price: '109.95',
    description: 'Your perfect pack for everyday use and walks in the forest. Stash your laptop (up to 15 inches) in the padded sleeve, your everyday',
    category: 'men clothing',
    image: 'https://fakestoreapi.com/img/81fPKd-2AYL._AC_SL1500_.jpg'
  }
]
```

Now I want to console log only the id and title field, how should I go about it? Many thanks in advance and greatly appreciate any helps. Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is: It is an array of objects from the console.log values. You can do this:

```
console.log(`Id: ${jsonObj[0].id}` and Title: ${jsonObj[0].title})
```

If you have multiple objects, you can loop through it like this:

```js
const jsonObj = [{
    id: '1',
    title: 'Fjallraven - Foldsack No. 1 Backpack, Fits 15 Laptops',
    price: '109.95',
    description: 'Your perfect pack for everyday use and walks in the forest. Stash your laptop (up to 15 inches) in the padded sleeve, your everyday',
    category: 'men clothing',
    image: 'https://fakestoreapi.com/img/81fPKd-2AYL._AC_SL1500_.jpg'
  }, {
   id: '2',
    title: 'Fjallraven - Foldsack No. 1 Backpack, Fits 15 Laptops',
    price: '109.95',
    description: 'Your perfect pack for everyday use and walks in the forest. Stash your laptop (up to 15 inches) in the padded sleeve, your everyday',
    category: 'men clothing',
    image: 'https://fakestoreapi.com/img/81fPKd-2AYL._AC_SL1500_.jpg'
  }]

jsonObj.forEach(el => console.log(`Id: ${el.id}, title: ${el.title}`));
```

Comment: hi Apoorva Chikara, thanks a lot for the array hint.